# How to add different CSS style to every nth element, depending on n using LESS

Tags: css, less, padding

I am trying to add different padding to subsequent elements in a div. My DOM looks pretty simple.

```
<div class="parent">
   <div>0</div>
   <div>15</div>
   <div>30</div>
   ...
</div>
```

So I would like for my first element to have 0 padding, my second 15, third 30 etc.
Using *LESS*, how could I make this work?
I have tried:

```
.parent div:nth-of-type(n) {
           padding-left: n*15px;
}
```

Thank you!

Comment: you can't with pure css - if it were less then you could do a loop to generate the css required - but it would output a line for each thing and you would need to know the max number of children - could you not just change the html and nest the divs?

Comment: can you use sass or scss?

Comment: Yes, I am using LESS.

Comment: see my answer about less

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using less(but you have to set the num of elements):

```
.parent (@indexstart,@index) when (@indexstart < @index ){
  div:nth-child(@{indexstart}){
    padding-left: (@indexstart - 1) * 15px;
  }
  .parent (@indexstart + 1,@index);
}
.parent (1,4);
```

[See example](https://codepen.io/leenmalka/pen/bQJOqY?page=1&)

Answer (score 6):

I suppose you want to achieve a stair visually. In this case you can do it like below:

```css
.parent {
  line-height: 1.2em;
}

.parent>div:not(:first-child)::before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  width: 15px; /*your padding*/
  height: calc(1.2em + 2px);

}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div>0</div>
  <div>15</div>
  <div>30</div>
  <div>45</div>
  <div>60</div>
  <div>75</div>
</div>
```

Comment: That's a really nice trick. Anyway, I think it needs a little something to be more visual. Maybe adding a background color and some more height on the pseudo-element (I can do it, if you'd like).

Comment: but are the children staggered because the children are or behave as blocks?

Comment: @oldboy add a coloration to the pseudo element to understand. The float is pushing the text because text wrap around float

Comment: yes, but what i am wondering is why each pseudo element respects the horizontal position of the former pseudo element?

Comment: @oldboy this is the magic of float ;) each float element is a bit bigger than the height of one div so the next float will get pushed and so on ... Actually I am using what everyone hate with floats. The strange layout you get when you don't clear float: this is what is happening here.

Comment: ohhhhhhhh that makes sense, the "not clearing floats," cuz arent all the pseudo elements the exact same size?

Comment: @oldboy yes they are the same size but more presicely their size need to be bigger that the size of one line. if you decrease the size less than 1.2em it won't work. any value bigger than 1.2em will work

Comment: ohhhhhhhh, okay, i finally understand, adding the `2px` creates the "push"