# Position Sticky While Offsetting Inline Elements

Tags: html, css, sticky

What I am trying to do is offset inline elements incrementally while using a sticky position on them, so that as the user scrolls the elements lock into place forming a coherent structure. For example, I have a parent element, `div`, which contains a `p` child, which in turn contains multiple `span` children.

```
<div>
  <p>
    <span>w</span>
    <span>o</span>
    <span>r</span>
    <span>d</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

What I have done is offset each letter incrementally using `translateY` (since `sticky` obviously uses `top`, etc, to determine the sticking point), so that the first letter is offset by, say, `100%`, the second letter by `200%`, so on and so forth. The idea is that each letter will lock into place as the user scrolls, eventually forming a word when the user is done scrolling.

I know that the problem is that as soon as I enable `sticky`, the `span` elements become positioned `relative` to the parent, which means the elements are ALWAYS offset relative to the parent. I just cannot figure out a pure CSS solution.

**I did get an idea while writing this: Perhaps the trick is to use `top` to offset, yet `bottom` for sticking?**

*[**Here**](https://codepen.io/tOkyO1/pen/OJXPbEj) is a codepen of the embedded code below.*

```css
html,
body { width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0; }

div  { border: solid red 2px; box-sizing: border-box; }

p    { font-family: arial; font-size: 104px; border: solid blue 2px; box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin: 0;
}

span { border: solid black 2px; box-sizing: border-box;
  /* position: sticky; */
  top: 0;
  display: inline-block;
}

span:nth-child(1) { transform: translateY(100%); }
span:nth-child(2) { transform: translateY(200%); }
span:nth-child(3) { transform: translateY(300%); }
span:nth-child(4) { transform: translateY(400%); }
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <span>w</span>
    <span>o</span>
    <span>r</span>
    <span>d</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a negative percentage on each letter to offset the transform:

```css
html,
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0;
}

div {
  border: solid red 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
  font-family: arial;
  font-size: 104px;
  border: solid blue 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin: 0;
}

span {
  border: solid black 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  position: sticky;
  display: inline-block;
}

span:nth-child(1) {
  transform: translateY(100%);
  top: -100%;
}

span:nth-child(2) {
  transform: translateY(200%);
  top: -200%;
}

span:nth-child(3) {
  transform: translateY(300%);
  top: -300%;
}

span:nth-child(4) {
  transform: translateY(400%);
  top: -400%;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <span>w</span>
    <span>o</span>
    <span>r</span>
    <span>d</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: its been a while since i coded last, so my coding brain isnt working at full capacity, but this is eloquent af nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

Here is another idea of solution more suitable for monospace font and generic (you don't need to set style using `nth-child`)

```css
div {
  border: solid red 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

p {
  font-family: monospace;
  font-size:90px;
  border: solid blue 2px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1.2em;
  height: 1.2em; /* equal to line-height */
}

span {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  display: block;
}

span:first-child {
  margin-top: 1.2em; /* equal to line-height */
}

span:not(:first-child)::before {
  content: "";
  float: left;
  width: 1ch;
  height: 1.3em; /* a bit bigger than the line-height */
}
```

```html
<div>
  <p>
    <span>H</span>
    <span>e</span>
    <span>l</span>
    <span>l</span>
    <span>o</span>
    <span> </span>
    <span>w</span>
    <span>o</span>
    <span>r</span>
    <span>d</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Comment: somebody beat u to it. appreciate it nonetheless tho <3

Comment: wicked!! monospaced fonts are a treasure. wish they fit the brand of what i was building :(

Comment: this works by inserting a pseudo element before every letter which assumes a `margin-top` from `span:first-child`? is that how the offset increments?

Comment: @oldboy it works due to the floating psuedo element that push the letter on each line. Here is a better illustration: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53611964/8620333