# Multiline inline-block element trails after multiline inline element

Tags: html, css, layout

I just found an interesting layout behavior using `display` and `white-space` property.

HTML

```html
<div>
<span>Lorem
ipsum</span> <span style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top">dolor
sit 
amet</span> <span style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top">consectetur
adipisicing
elit</span>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
* {
  white-space: pre;
}
```

You can check it here. https://jsfiddle.net/asdasd111/ct71n36w/2/

As you can see, it looks like `dolor sit amet` trail after `Lorem ipsum`, aligned the end of the last line of `Lorem ipsum`.
I've tried to make `consectetur adipisicing elit` also trail after `dolor sit amet` like the following. While `Lorem ipsum` is trailed by `dolor sit amet`, `dolor sit amet` is **trailing** but not **trailed**.

```
Lorem
ipsum dolor
      sit 
      amet consectetur
           adipisicing
           elit
```

However, I can't find the way and I'm not sure even if it is possible.

Can I achieve only with CSS without changing the HTML structure?
In other words, I hope that I have a class named `trailing-and-trailed` and all I need to do is just applying it to the elements regardless of each one's width and height

```html
<div>
<span>Lorem
ipsum</span> <span style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top">dolor
sit 
amet</span> <span style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top">consectetur
adipisicing
elit</span> <span style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top">sed
do
eiusmod
tempor
incididunt
</span> <span style="display:inline-block;vertical-align:top">ut
labore
et
dolore
manga
aliqua
</span>
<!-- so on -->
</div>
```

```
Lorem
ipsum dolor
      sit 
      amet consectetur
           adipisicing
           elit sed 
                do
                eiusmod
                tempor
                incididunt ut
                           labore
                           et
                           dolore
                           manga
                           aliqua
```

like this.

Comment: Questions seeking code help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**  preferably in a **Stack Snippet**. Although you have provided a link, if it was to become invalid, your question would be of no value to other future SO users with the same problem. See [**Something in my website/example doesn't work can I just paste a link**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/254428/something-in-my-web-site-or-project-doesnt-work-can-i-just-paste-a-link-to-it).

Comment: Not in the same manner, you can't. You could add a ::before pseudo-element or margin top to achieve the *effect*, but the layout is fundamentally different.

Comment: You may be able to use the same HTML structure, but it depends on exactly what you want, how general you want the solution to be. Is there to be different amounts of text/number of lines etc in each block and if so is the next block always to start inline with the last line of the previous one or after the first line?

Comment: I want to achieve it by applying the same CSS rules to every trailing element regardless of each element's width and height and the total number of trailing elements.

Comment: Having the same CSS rules for all trailing elements is a stricter condition than you put in your question. I think you'd better expand your question to include all the constraints as well as showing any code you have already tried.

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53611964/8620333

Comment: will your content only hello worlds? only two lines? we need more constraint to give accurate answers